# Как называется сервис(как на фото)для просмотра дизайна сайта

Tags: html, css, веб-дизайн, responsive

Как называется сервис(как на фото)для просмотра дизайна сайта или что то похожее
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что здесь не гадание по картинкам

Comment: Ок а если я просто задам вопрос и опишу функционал сервиса?)По моему изображение упростило бы нахождение ответа

Comment: Неуместные тэги, странный вопрос, не касающийся разработки. Для таких вопросов не составит труда в поисковых системах поискать ответ

Comment: www.responsivedesigntest.net

Comment: Спасибо)помогло

Comment: Также в гугле хроме магазе пропишите responsive - вам выдаст много плагинов для проверки совместимости устройств

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Также в гугле хроме магазе пропишите responsive - вам выдаст много плагинов для проверки совместимости устройств